# Find out if an ArrayList has a certain char or partial string in it and then print the results

Tags: java, arraylist

The flowing code doesn't show if it contains just a char, like 'a', in the flower name

```
private static void filterFlower (ArrayList<Flower> flower) {

    String floName = getString("Enter the partial name of the flower: ");

    boolean flr = flower.contains(floName);

    if (flr == true) {
        System.out.println("\nThe Flowers are filtered by " + floName + "\n");
        System.out.println(floName);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("There isn't a flower with the following: "+ floName + " " + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your Flower class have a equals definition based on its member flowerName? You're trying to match a String object to your Flower object.

Comment: You are comparing String to a Flower

Comment: I did originally have an equals definition in this method but changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Flower class has a `name` member and a getter for it:

```
private static void filterFlower (ArrayList<Flower> flowers) {

    String partialName = getString("Enter the partial name of the flower: ");

    ArrayList<Flower> filteredFlowers = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    for(Flower flower: flowers){
        if (flower.getName().contains(partialName)){
            filteredFlowers.add(flower);
        }
    }
    if (filteredFlowers.size() > 0){
        System.out.println("The flowers containing " + partialName + " are: ");
        for(Flower flower: filteredFlowers){
            System.out.println(flower.getName());
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("None of the flowers contain " + partialName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work (untested):

```
 boolean contains = false;
 String floName = getString("Enter the partial name of the flower: ");
 for(Flower f : flower) {
     contains |= f.getName().contains(floName);
     if (contains) {
        System.out.println("\nThe Flowers are filtered by " + floName + "\n");
        System.out.println(floName);
        return;
     }
 }
 System.out.println("There isn't a flower with the following: "+ floName);
```

Comment: where exactly did he mention he has a getName() method in FLower class ? unless ur implying he should have one ;)

Comment: He should either have a getName() or a toString(). I had to pick one, and getName() seamed the logic choice ;)

Comment: This method only prints out the exact one. I need one which prints out any element in the list that contains a certain char or partial string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a collection of flowers, you will need to loop through the collection and compare each item. What you choose to do after, depends on what you want the application to accomplish.

This code is slightly different than yours, but you will get the idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Flower> flowers = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    flowers.add(new Flower("Amaranth"));
    flowers.add(new Flower("Anemone"));
    flowers.add(new Flower("Amaryllis"));
    filterFlower(flowers);
}
```

Also, since your argument is a collection, it makes sense to rename it to flowers as it will be easier to see what it actually is (without reading the type declaration).

```
private static void filterFlower (ArrayList<Flower> flowers) {
    System.out.print("Enter the partial name of the flower: ");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String partial = scanner.next();

    ArrayList<Flower> matchedFlowers = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    for (Flower flower : flowers){
        if(flower.contains(partial))
            matchedFlowers.add(flower);
    }

    if (matchedFlowers.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No match for '" + partial + "'");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Matches for '" + partial + "':");
        for(Flower flower : matchedFlowers){
            System.out.println(flower.name);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will work given that you also have defined the Flower as follows:

```
public class Flower {
   public String name;
   public Flower(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }
   public boolean contains(String partial){
      return name.contains(partial);
   }
}
```

*This code surely can be written even more clear, and optimized for that matter. You can even rewrite it in many different ways (even if it's a simple application). I still think it answers your question.*

Comment: It needs to print all the flowers which contain the given string or char